# two-way DB synchronization

Tags: java, database, postgresql, synchronization, firebird

I have two applications (back office with java + postgres and a lot of desktop applications with delphi and firebird). I need two-way synchronization of some tables. I see few ways of this:

1. Changesets. I have some table on both sides with changesets. Something like: number, type (create, update, delete), entity name and json or xml data. So, desktop can ask back office changesets from some number and get actual state. If something creates on desktop, it sends changeset to backend
2. Every synchronized table has modify date column. So, we can ask back office rows from some date. I have soft delete, so delete is update. In this case I can track delete actions too. Also I should send changes from desktop to back office
3. Every synchronized table has hash row. So, we can ask data with mismatch hashes.  Also I should send changes from desktop to back office

Could you suggest me the best way? Or maybe you have better ideas.

Comment: What about replication? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication

Comment: Replication is good idea. But, on desctop apps I have firebird (not postgres). Also I do not need full sync. Every desctop app is a customer. In back office I have data for all customers. And desctop app should have only its own data

Answer (score 0):

Just worked on a such project, Delphi+Firebird with synchronization of some data.
Having the master (main server) database and the client database, I've added 2 fields for tables that need to be synchronized (master_id, slave_id) and made a service application that runs on a specified interval of time and uploads the data on Master filling the master_id in the Slave fields. Do that record by record or bulk.